# Identificar se uma string está em maiúsculo no sql server!

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Tenho um campo em uma tabela que deve ser preenchida toda em minúscula, porém o usuário sendo usuário preencheu algumas linhas em maiúscula. Quero identificar quais registros estão assim para poder solicitar correção.

Tenho como testar se minha string está toda em maiúscula?

Comment: Você deseja testar se ela tem letras em maiúsculo ou que esteja toda em maiúsculo?

Comment: Imagine que você tenha esse valor no seu campo: `TEXTO Correto`, estaria ou correto ou errado?

Comment: A necessidade é de descobrir se o campo tem o texto inteiro em MAÍUSCULO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar o `COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI` na sua validação da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @texto_normal VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @texto_minusculo VARCHAR(100);

SET @texto_normal = 'Normal';
SET @texto_minusculo = 'minusculo';

IF LOWER(@texto_normal) <> @texto_normal COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI
BEGIN
  PRINT '@texto_normal tem maiúsculas';
END;

IF LOWER(@texto_minusculo) <> @texto_minusculo COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI
BEGIN
  PRINT '@texto_minusculo tem maiúsculas';
END;
```

Ou para usar em uma `query`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE LOWER(t.campo) <> t.campo COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI;
```

O `CS_` no seletor diz que o texto é `case sensitive`.

---

Referência: [Collation and Unicode Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support)

Comment: +1 massa ......

Comment: Obrigado @sorack. Consegui chegar ao que eu queria utilizando a query que você informou.

Comment: @RafaelDantas se a resposta lhe atendeu, marque-a como correta para que outros usuários possam se beneficiar da sua pergunta