# O que COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI faz?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou fazendo essa pergunta pois me deparei com essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209763/identificar-se-uma-string-est%C3%A1-em-mai%C3%BAsculo-no-sql-server#209763) do @Sorack; Eu não entendi qual a influência que *`COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI`* teve no resultado,  já vi algumas respostas aqui no *StackOverflow* e fiquei sem entender o real uso disto.

- O que significa *`COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI`*?
- Onde isto é aplicável?
- O que isso faz?

Creio que um exemplo facilitaria o entendimento.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do COLLATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) (traduzido by Google) é:

> `COLLATE` é uma cláusula que pode ser aplicada a uma definição de banco de dados ou a uma definição de coluna para definir o agrupamento ou a uma expressão de seqüência de caracteres para aplicar um elenco de agrupamento.

Em resumo, especifica o conjunto de caracteres e regras que está utilizando.

Ao separar o `COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI`, temos a seguintes funções.

**LATIN1**: Define o [charset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/mapping-mysql-and-sql-server-character-set-mysqltosql) que será utilizado. Você pode fazer isso para o banco ou por consulta, como mostrado na resposta que você postou.

**CS:**  Especifica como *Case Sensitive*;

**AI:** Especifica como *Accent Insensitive.*

Também temos outras opções, como:

**CI:** Especifica como *Case Insensitive*.

**AS:** Especifica como *Accent Sensitive*.

**BIN:** Especifica a ordem de classificação a ser utilizada como binária.

#### Mas o que isso tudo quer dizer?

Veja o código abaixo:

```
DECLARE @texto varchar(50);
SET @texto = 'Olhe VOCÊ, está querendo aprender sobre COLLATES?';

--Retorno: True
 SELECT CASE WHEN @texto LIKE '%voce%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI THEN  'True' ELSE 'False' END
 --Retorno False
 SELECT CASE WHEN @texto LIKE '%voce%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AI THEN  'True' ELSE 'False' END
 --Retorno: False
 SELECT CASE WHEN @texto LIKE '%voce%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AS THEN  'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

Em todos os casos eu estou buscando se existe a palavra **voce** em qualquer lugar da frase.

Note que no primeiro `SQL` eu estou utilizando `AI` (Accent Insensitie) , ou seja, acentos não me interessam e  `CI` (Case Insensitive), ou seja, não me importa se tiverem caracteres maiúsculos ou minúsculos. E com isso o meu resultado será `True`, pois no texto eu possuo a palavra **VOCÊ** no texto.

Nos outros casos, onde eu estou utilizando `CS` e `AS`, os resultados são `False`, pois quero que ele considere os acentos e diferencie maiúsculas de minúsculas.

Caso queira ler mais sobre isso, veja alguns links abaixo:

- [SQL Server Collation Name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/sql-server-collation-name-transact-sql)
- [Collations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations)
- [What does 'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5039211/4843158)

Comment: Excelente resposta

Comment: Nas partes em negrito `CS e CI` e `AI e AS` estão descritos da mesma forma, é isto mesmo @Randrade?

Comment: @Marconi Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas o `CS e CI` são Case Sensitive e o outro é Case Insensitive. O `AS e AI` são Accents Sensitive e Accent Insensitive .