# Retornar um registro case sensitive

Tags: sql, string, oracle

Eu possuo uma `constraint` no banco que está toda com seu nome em maiúsculo. Como eu faço um `count` pra encontrar a mesma usando o `UPPER`? Pois quero passar no `where` um nome em minúsculo pra retornar. Essa minha *query* não está funcionando.

```
select count(*)
 from all_cons_columns
 where UPPER(constraint_name) = 'FK_od8ou6g1l9t7iufcp3o0to189';
```

Ou seja, retorna 0 quando deveria retornar 1. Se eu colocar o nome como está no banco retorna 1.

Answer (score 5):

Se deseja compar tudo maiúsculo então compare com o outro lado tudo maiúsculo também:

```
select count(*)
 from all_cons_columns
 where UPPER(constraint_name) = 'FK_OD8OU6G1L9T7IUFCP3O0TO189';
```

Na verdade o ideal seria usar um [`COLLATE`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209779/101) que não considere o `*casing*. Veja [artigo sobre o assunto](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2).

Se fosse uma variável como parãmetro aí seria:

```
select count(*)
 from all_cons_columns
 where UPPER(constraint_name) = UPPER(parametro);
```

Se é garantido que a coluna sempre será maiúscula seria:

```
select count(*)
 from all_cons_columns
 where constraint_name = UPPER(parametro);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CaseSensitiveness.sql).

Qualquer coisa que fuja disto não faz sentido. De qualquer forma é um paliativo, usar a *collation*  é o mais correto.

Comment: Isso não me atende porque eu sempre vou receber o nome em minúsculo.

Comment: Receberá onde??

Comment: Minha situação é a seguinte: Imagina que no banco a constraint já existe. Me pedem para verificar se a mesma já existe. Quando me solicitam, me falam o nome dela com o nome minúsculo. Eu teria que converter pra maiúsculo pra depois fazer a query ? Não, eu quero que o select retorne se ela existe independente como eu coloquei no where.

Comment: Não estou entendendo nada o que está querendo, não sei o que `constraint` tem a ver com isso, não sei de onde vem essa informação que está dizendo, não sei porque está falando em minúsculo agora quando na pergunta está maiúsculo, ou qual a dificuldade. Se não vai usar um *collating* então tem que fazer os dois lado serem tudo maiúsculo ou tudo minúsculo, isto não importa.

Comment: Eu achei a solução, vou postar e talvez fique mais claro qual foi a minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

A solução era passar o UPPER no nome da constraint:

```
select count(*)
 from all_cons_columns
 where constraint_name = UPPER('FK_od8ou6g1l9t7iufcp3o0to189');
```

Comment: Isto não faz o menor sentido, se já está tudo maiúsculo não tem porque usar um `UPPER()`.

Comment: Editei a resposta, agora sim faz sentido. Eu passo no where o nome em minúsculo.

Comment: Ainda não faz sentido porque basta você escrever já em maiúsculo, não precisa da função.